# jQuery tabs reloading content

Tags: jquery-ui

I have an application that uses jQuery tabs to display different dynamic content for the user.  The user has the ability to subscribe to various information feeds into "pods" on each tab.  So for example the first tab might have 4 pods and each pod on the tab displays different information.  The user has the ability to select a different template for each tab (like 4 smaller pods, or 2 larger ones, etc).

I have built a user interface to allow the user to rename the tab and to change the template that is displayed in that tab.  The problem is when the user changes the template for a tab, the tab does not refresh/reload to show the new template.  The only way to display the new template is to reload the whole screen.

I have tried using the following code after the tab has been updated in the database

```
$("#tabselector").tabs("load", tabindex);
```

However the above does not seem to reload the tab.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You probably need to post some more code: how you created the tabs and how is the new template inserted into the tab?

Comment: What does "the tab has been updated in the database" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I got your question, but I'll try to guess what you are after from the last paragraph of your question.

If you want to change the URL of the remote/AJAX tab, you need to use the `.tabs( "url" , index , url )` method. The `load` method will not load the tab again if it is already loaded. See the [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/).

Comment: +1 - Thanks William!  First, sorry for the poorly written question, but it is kind of complicated and I think I made it more complicated.  Anyway, I came to the same answer on my own after I realized that I needed to update the url that jQuery was using or else jQuery would have just reloaded the tab with the old URL.